# Can a hierarchy of fixed points potentially be used to describe a kinetic energy spectrum which is composed of multiple scale invariant subranges?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fluid-dynamics, renormalization, turbulence

Making use of a nonequilibrium functional renormalization group [(Berges and Mesterhazy, 2012)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1489) are able to investigate a whole hierarchy of fixed points that explain the successive evolution of a system from a nonequilibrium state to  equilibrium. Can such an appoach be applied to investigate the transition between two inertial subranges in atmospheric turbulence too?

I am asking about this, since the illustration of a dual cascade in fugure 1 of the paper

[image]

Looks quite similar to the TKE spectra one observes in atmospheric turbulence.

[image]

In both cases, the different regimes are associated with with a stationary transport of conserved quanitities.

So, is this similarity I percieve only superficial and misguided, or should it in principle be possible for example to describe the kinks in the Nastrom-Gage spectra by such dual cascades too? And if so, has there already some work on this be done or is under way?